# I would like to move a button based on a joint position with Kinect v2

Tags: c#, wpf, button, kinect

My intention is to track a joint with the Kinect v2, and then move a button in a Canvas based on that joint position.
My problem is the buttons: they don't move and stay still

Here is my code:

```
if (joint.JointType == JointType.SpineMid) {
    ColorSpacePoint space =
    this.kinectRegion.KinectSensor.CoordinateMapper.MapCameraPointToColorSpace(joint.Position);
    Point center = new Point(space.X, space.Y);
    Point[] verticies = Polygon.CalculateVertices(buttons.Count, radius,
                                                  startingAngle, center);

    int i = 0;
    foreach (var button in buttons)
    {
        choices.Add(verticies[i], button);
        i++;
    }

    foreach (var obj in choices)
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(obj.Value, obj.Key.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(obj.Value, obj.Key.Y);
    }

    choices.Clear();

}
```

The buttons are declared in the MainWindow.xaml file as:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Panel.ZIndex="1" Height="200" Width="200" Margin="0,436,1712,444" Background="Aqua" Visibility="Hidden" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.02,0.565" />
<Button x:Name="button2" Panel.ZIndex="1" Height="200" Width="200" Margin="927,10,785,870" Background="Aqua" Visibility="Hidden" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.02,0.565" />
<Button x:Name="button3" Panel.ZIndex="1" Height="200" Width="200" Margin="927,849,785,31" Background="Aqua" Visibility="Hidden" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.02,0.565" />
<Button x:Name="button4" Panel.ZIndex="1" Height="200" Width="200" Margin="1702,436,10,444" Background="Aqua" Visibility="Hidden" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.02,0.565" />

<Button x:Name="backButton" Visibility="Visible" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" Click="GoBack" />
```

verticies contains the point from the buttons.
choices is: `Dictionary<Point, Button> choices = new Dictionary<Point,Button>();`

Comment: Please format you code so people can actually read it.

Comment: `"Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first"` seems pretty straight forward. You need to remove the button from whatever it's currently placed in before adding it to another. It can't ever have two parents.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to place the Buttons into `Canvas` again? You can simply change their `Canvas.Left` a `Canvas.Top` properties and they will be moved.

Comment: You're right and I've alredy deleted that part of the code in my project. Now I'm editing the code above